# What values the coeff can take if the system is consistent?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $a, b, c, d$ are constants and if $a \neq 0$ and the system is consistent for all possible values of $f$ and $g$, what can be said about the numbers $a, b, c, d$ ?

$$ax_1+bx_2=f$$

$$cx_1+dx_2=g$$

$\underline{\text{My thoughts:}} $ guess any

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{cases}
ax_1+bx_2=f
\\
cx_1+dx_2=g
\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}
acx_1+bcx_2=fc
\\
acx_1+adx_2=ag
\end{cases}$$
Then $$(bc-ad)x_2=fc-ag$$
$$x_2=\frac{fc-ag}{bc-ad}$$
$$\Delta=bc-ad\not=0$$
For $x_1 -$ similarly

If $\Delta=bc-ad\not=0$ then one solution $(x_1,x_2)$.

**Or so**

$\frac{a}{c}\not=\frac{b}{d} \Rightarrow $ one solution $(x_1,x_2)$.

$\frac{a}{c}=\frac{b}{d}=\frac fg \Rightarrow $ an infinite number of solutions

$\frac{a}{c}=\frac{b}{d}\not=\frac fg \Rightarrow $ no solutions

I think the answer: $bc\not=ad, a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$